# WPF / Avalonia: How can you "inject" / insert a control itself in a templated control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, avalonia

Most of the code in this question is in Avalonia, but an equivalent can be made in WPF with almost the same syntax.

Say I have this templated control:

```xml
    <Style Selector="controls|ExampleControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ExampleControl}">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="*"
                      ColumnDefinitions="3*, *"
                      ShowGridLines="True">

                    <!-- The window should insert a control at column 0 of the grid here. -->

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="Hi!"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And a window that uses it:

```xml
<controls:ExampleControl ???=???/>
```

**My goal is to create a control somewhere in the window and have the templated control use it. How do I achieve this?**

For example's sake, the control to be added by the window is a `TextBlock` with its `Text` bound to a property `LabelText` from a viewmodel / its code-behind.

Comment: I am really struggling with this too, and I can't find any easy-to-understand example. This seems related: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/11462 But I can't really translate it to working code.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, the `ExampleControl` should inherit from `ContentControl` and include a `ContentPresenter` in its template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ExampleControl}">
    <Grid>

        <ContentPresenter />

        ...

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can then set the `Content` of the  `ContentControl`:

```
<controls:ExampleControl>
    <TextBlock>contents...</TextBlock>
</controls:ExampleControl>
```